# Rails test offline application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, tdd, cucumber, capybara-webkit

Does anyone know how to test offline part of the application using cucumber or jasmine?

Currently our team is developing application using backbonejs,localStorage,backbone-queues libraries for making possible for users to work offline in the modern browsers and syncing data through ajax requests.

But we need to test our application using user scenarios like cucumber steps because we need to clarify all our development steps with our customer.

We got the next following issue with cucumber/capybara-webkit gem. it doesn't support html5 features like localStorage(ok, we made fork of one guy from github and merged it with the latest sources of capybara-webkit). but we got another problem. How to simulate reopen/close browser actions or how to clean localStorage for each scenario. now scenarios are using the same localStorage.

May be someone has experience in such of testing applications.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clear the local storage by calling:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('YOUR_KEY', '{}')")
```

Comment: Did you try it in your project with capybara-webkit driver? and it would work if you have already opened the browser. but if you should have cleaned up localStorage before loading the page. I think it should not work.